# Oracle rownum in range

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

How to return datas from oracle database in range of rowum, this doesnot work

```
select *from(
select * from t where  date>=sysdate-1 order by date desc
) where ROWNUM>=20 and ROWNUM<=40
```

Comment: Use analytical function `row_number` inplace of `rownum`. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FHXEW8QV9BNS5LUN2GTMYWWFL.html

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 12C+, you can use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select *
from t
where date >= sysdate - 1
order by date desc
offset 19 fetch next 21 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1):

rownum is set as the rows are output from the query, so you need to include it in your inline view and apply filter outside the view:-

```
select * from (
select *, rownum as r from t where  date>=sysdate-1 order by date desc
) where r>=20 and r<=40
```

Comment: IIRC, the inner query must use the table name in the select clause, i.e. `select t.*, rownum as r`